# Calling an overloaded function method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a function that returns a list of parts in our catalog.

The function works as intended, but I've since found the need to also create an overloaded function that returns only a subset of the whole parts catalog.

Currently, I have written the original function and overloaded function like this.

```
Public Function GetpartsList() As IEnumerable(Of PartsWarehouse)
    Return From p In mySession.Query(Of PartsWarehouse)()
End Function

Public Function GetpartsList(Engine As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of PartsWarehouse)
    Return From p In mySession.Query(Of PartsWarehouse)() _
    .Where(Function(p) p.IsEngineOnly)
End Function
```

And I call both functions like this.

```
GetPartsList()
GetPartsList(isEngine)
```

But this seems kind of counter intuitive because even though I pass in a value for 'Engine', I never really use it.

Is there a more logical way of overloading this function? Perhaps I should just have one function, and include some sort of if/else logic inside.

Comment: Could the overloaded version be more general if you used a type of part?  Don't know what fields / properties are returned so it is hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
Public Function GetpartsList(optional Engine As Boolean = false) As IEnumerable(Of PartsWarehouse)
    dim query = mySession.Query(Of PartsWarehouse)()
    if Engine then
      query = query.Where(Function(p) p.IsEngineOnly)
    end if
    return query.ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, I didn't think about including an optional parameter like that. Thanks

Comment: @999cm999 With optional parameters always keep in mind that the optional value is bound to the call site.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an overload but a different function.  You could take a boolean as a paramater but then what happens if you need to create another sub set in this case it would be better and clearer to the consumer if you had

```
Public Function GetEngines()...
Public Function GetPartsList()...
```